# Get value of input with a variable id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get the value of a selected object in a table.

the id's are auto generated like to resemble this

> ( status1, status2, status3....)

I use the following to extract the row id

```
var $row = this.id.match(/\d+/); // Extract number to get row id
```

and then I want to concatenate that row id to get the value of the column, like this

```
var $hasID = $("hasid"+$row).val();
```

but `$hasID` remains `UNDEFINED`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix `#` when using ID selector. Since `match` will return you an array use `[0]` to get first element.

*Use*

```
var $hasID = $("#hasid" + $row[0]).val();
```